# Dependency injection for request variables in a web application

Tags: php, web-applications, dependency-injection, globals

I'm working a PHP 5.5/MySQL web application.

If a class depends partly on some global GET and POST variables for its members, should I just refer to them directly from within the class, or should I have them as arguments in the constructor or some other initiating function?

```
class myclass {
  protected $id;
  public function __construct() {
    $this->id = (int)$_GET['id'];
  }
}
$myclass = new myclass();
```

Or

```
class myclass {
  protected $id;
  public function __construct($id) {
    $this->id = (int)$id;
  }
}
$myclass = new myclass($_GET['id']);
```

How do MVC frameworks handle this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Another important point is unit testing. If you inject the dependencies of a class, you can easily instantiate them in unit tests.

You might want to look at Misko Hevery's
[clean code talk about global state](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/11/21/clean-code-talks-global-state-and-singletons/) (He has few other good talks about OOD)

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of DI is to make your functions independent from the *Environment*, namely the *Global* variables. That means:

```
function bad () {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    ...
```

Is as *Bad* as:

```
function bad () {
    global $db;
    ...
```

In both examples you need to pass the function/method dependencies via function arguments. To understand it better imagine if at some point you needed to create an instance of the class, but when you don't have the `id` in the query string. Another example is if you later decided to implement the same functionality via *POST* as well. So you need to go and replace all of those `$_GET` variables with `$_REQUEST`.

So if I were you I'd definitely go for the second approach. Also it is not related to *MVC* design-pattern at all. Different frameworks might suggest different practices or don't suggest anything at all.

Comment: You have to put $_GET['id'] somewhere, though. Should it be outside of all classes, in a functional area of the code? Or should there be a class whose sole purpose is to take globals into itself and instantiate objects of other classes based on them?